# Why $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$, for infinite sets $A_i$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

At pg. #6, of the book: Understanding Analysis
by Stephen Abbott, it is given that the intersection of infinite collection of sets of naturals, with successively increasing first element, yields null set. It is shown [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=Understanding%20Analysis%20Stephen%20Abbott%20The%20notion%20of%20intersection%20has%20the%20same%20kind%20of%20natural%20extension%20to%20infinite%20collections%20of%20sets.&source=bl&ots=DUBqFGoRoF&sig=Z-koxwskrag56lTbJMOmHTFUYig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisnJaRx4DfAhWPXSsKHfd0BgQQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Understanding%20Analysis%20Stephen%20Abbott%20The%20notion%20of%20intersection%20has%20the%20same%20kind%20of%20natural%20extension%20to%20infinite%20collections%20of%20sets.&f=false).

It states:

$A_1 = \mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$ 
$A_2 = \{2, 3, 4, \cdots \}$ 
$A_3 = \{3, 4, 5, \cdots \}$

and, in general, for each $n\in  \mathbb{N}$, define the set

$A_n = \{n, n+1, n+2, \cdots \}$.

The result is a nested chain of sets:

$A_1\supseteq  A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq A_4\supseteq \cdots$,

Then the book states: $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$
I can understand that had the sets been finite sets, i.e. with upper limit fixed, then it is possible if the upper end varies (by extending towards right) like the lower end in this case. 
But, for infinite sets it is quite possible that the infinite end has common elements.

Comment: What sort of number would you think may be an element of the intersection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, then $x \in A_n$ for all $n \geq 1$. Since the least element of each $A_n$ is $n$, this means $x \geq n$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Thus $x$ will be bigger then every natural number, which is a contradiction. Thus no such $x$ exists.

Comment: Please state some relevant known results, based on this, also. I feel this must be a well known principle.

Comment: @jiten I am not sure what results are you looking for.

Comment: @jiten The only "well-known principle" that I see is relevant here, is that elements of an intersection of sets are are elements of all the sets being intersected.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrased a bit.

Assume $\cap A_{n=1}^{\infty} \not = \emptyset.$

There is a $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$m \in \cap A_{n=1}^{\infty}.$

Since $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ there is a successor $m+1 >m$.

Since $m \not \in A_{m+1}$ we get

$m \not \in \cap A_{n=1}^{\infty}$, a contradiction .